# Steps to take when planning and executing a new project (say mobile app)

Tags: mobile

I want to build a free app to become familiar with what is required, but I was always confused about the steps one needs to take to START a software project.

What are the steps required in order to develop a mobile app?

I will list some of the things I think should be done but I don't necessarily know how to do.  Any advice, details and technologies you have to accomplish these steps would be awesome.

- Decide which platform you want to develop.  What are some of the pros and cons in this area for android vs iOS vs Windows8?
- How to test the app - can you get free hardware to test with a well detailed app plan? Emulator?
- Detail what you want the app to do and which functionalities you want.
- Research if this app already exists.  What are some areas of concerns in terms of not breaking the law such as patent infringement etc?
- Setup a source repository such as git (google a guide I guess?)
- Look at guides to familiarize yourself with APIs and write sample code to learn what you need?
- Start the development and keep doing the above as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a software project can be as easy as start writing code. Most programmers will have an intuition as to what needs to be done and how it could be done. The other extreme of starting a software project is to start with talking to a client (or looking at the world) and figuring out what the problem is. I find that a thorough understanding of the problem you are trying to address with a project is already a long way into getting the project done painlessly. It'll give you a good understanding of what is required for you to call your project **done**.

So I guess point number one becomes: *know what the problem is you're solving*. Knowing this will also tell you if any existing app solves the same problem to a satisfying standard.

NOTE: I am not that familiar with the Windows 8 platform so my answer mostly talks about iOS and Android. The issues raised however are broad enough to cover large parts of the Windows platform.

> Platform

Selecting  a deployment platform is an important part of a launching a product, and a lot of other decisions depend on the platform. We are in the unfortunate state that two major mobile OSes exist that are separate in terms of code development and reuse. When considering selecting your deployment platform you'll want to think about the audience, and the (potential) sub set of the audience that is willing to pay for your application. Android might have to most devices out there but [iPhone makes the most money](http://git-scm.com) (also for developers). However, remember that there are lots of apps out there and most developers don't ever make any (or not enough) money out of their apps.

Getting into app development with the aim of getting rich is going to leave you dissappointed. That's not very likely, then again someone always wins the lottery as well. It is a good way though to get employed and make some money that way.

Then there is the question of programming language (Java, Objective-C or C#). This is largely decided on what you are already familiar with, and if you aren't then refer back to the previous point.

---

> Testing

Testing the product is a tricky thing. You'll have to start off with the emulator (which is usually provided with the development pack). Sooner or later however you'll have to test the app on hardware. I doubt you'll get your hands on free hardware but borrowing from friends and relatives is always an option. There may also be businesses that rent out test hardware to developers, if there isn't then I suppose that's one business idea to work on.

The platform choice will affect this also. Android is running on a much wider range of hardware than iOS.

---

> Patent infringment

I don't know that much about patent issues, other than software patents are nasty. As a single developer I wouldn't be too worried about infringing on patents, the main purpose of them is to keep competitors at bay. What usually ends up happening is that big companies kill off competition with patent lawsuits, or they buy a smaller company that holds a nice collection of patents.

If you want to be on the safe side (meaning you own a company and are really doing this to make money) then talk to patent lawyers.

---

> Code repository

A code hosting service like GitHub is fantastic in that it not only provides a place to have you code, but it also provides issue trackers for keeping notes on the functionality that is still missing or bugs that have crept up in your software.

The best places to start learning about Git are [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com) and the [GitHub help pages](https://help.github.com/).

---

> Software development plan

Your last point explodes to a thing called software engineering. There has been lots of research into different ways of managing software development projects. The idea being that software development tends to be extended over long periods of time, the requirements of the project change during the project (as you learn more) and the project can involve anything from 1 to 100s of developers. Some way coordinating work between those developers (and all other parties involved like customers) has to be formalised, enter software engineering. The aim is to define a methodology and project structure that guides the development process and makes it more likely that the requirements are met at the end of the project.

Some models worth looking into include (Test Driven Development and other agile methods).

---

Finally I would add to the list of things that need to be done

- Research libraries, note that this comes before familiarising yourself with the APIs of those libraries.

What software already exists that does a part of what you want to achieve. This goes partly back to the question of what platform to use. Apple has put a lot of attention in developing easy to use frameworks to support iOS app development. I am not that familiar with Andoird's or Windows 8 but the less code you have to write the faster the product will be done.

[1](http://git-scm.com) http://mobiledevices.about.com/od/kindattentiondevelopers/tp/Android-Os-Vs-Apple-Ios-Which-Is-Better-For-Developers.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is only one step needed: **Just start that project**!

You are going to develop a free application, so it should be fun to do that. Choose whatever you like  and keep going:

1. Make sure you are productive enough -- [10 Laws of Productivity](http://99u.com/tips/6585/10-Laws-of-Productivity)
2. Avoid complexity -- [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)
3. Let [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system do the boring stuff -- [Machines should work; people should think.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IBM_Pollyanna_Principle)
4. Read books and improve yourself.

Please also avoid blind decisions. If you simply try several available options you'll eventually find the best way to achieve your goals. Do some [PoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Concept) and decide. Nowadays 1-2 hours should be enough to start with any technology. This is the rule of maturity. You have your own goals, so it is better to avoid immature solutions.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

CPlayer I came to this forum with the same question since I am new to mobile app design and want to make my own app. I realize it is important to take certain steps in the correct order so that wasted time is minimized or eliminated. I did some research and came across two online sources I believe, if they are put together as one, will make one better source. The links are:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2311-a-mobile-app-development-checklist/

http://mobiledevices.about.com/od/kindattentiondevelopers/ht/How-To-Create-An-App-For-The-Iphone.htm

Good Luck,
laroice

Comment: Considerer including a summary of the links, and how you think they have to be put together.